# Split binary using input and ignore constant length of binary string in Java

Tags: java, string, binary

I want to split binary with input. i try to divide with input '6', so I get an error. because the length of binary string not a multiple of 6.

the result must be show the last binary even though not a multiple of six.

**My code**

```
static String s="";

public static String countBit(String message)
{
    int k = Integer.parseInt(Test2.s);
    String result="";
    long m=0L;
    for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i += k) 
    {    
        result += message.substring(i, i + k) + " ";
        long n = Long.parseLong(message.substring(i, i+k), 2);
        m = n;
        System.out.print(m+" ");
    }
    return result;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String message = "0101100010000100011000000100010000010000010000000000000001101101";

    BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

    System.out.print("Input bit split = ");
    s=br.readLine();
    System.out.println("\nBinary = "+countBit(message));
}
```

When I input bit split by 8, it's show every binary and decimal. and when I try to input by 6, I get error because binary string not multiple of 6.

the output must be like this:

```
22 8 17 32 17 1 1 0 0 6 13
```

**Binary**

```
010110 001000 010001 100000 010001 000001 000001 000000 000000 000110 1101
```

Comment: You can check to see min value `Math.min(i + k, message.length())` in the substring functions. Also, you want to print `n` instead of `m`.

Comment: how `000000` can be `98`, are you sure about the outputs?

Comment: @YCF_L Cause he is adding numbers each time so it adds 0.

Comment: sorry. i forget.. @YCF_L

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just the for loop from your code:

```
for(int i = 0; i < message.length(); i += k) 
{    
    result += message.substring(i, Math.min(i + k, message.length() - 1)) + " ";
    long n = Long.parseLong(message.substring(i, Math.min(i + k, message.length() - 1)), 2);
    m += n;
    System.out.print(n+" ");
}
```

Used `Math.min(i + k, message.length() - 1)` to ensure that it doesn't go out of bounds. Also, changed the `System.out` to print `n` instead of `m`.

Comment: sorry the last bit , it's wrong. why only 110? it must be 1101? so the decimal in last binary is 13? why you minus 1 on the message length?

Comment: nice catching +1, I think the op not need `m += n;` check the edit

Comment: Yea. He edited that after I posted the answer. He doesn't need to use the variable `m` at all in that case.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Java 8 you can use :

```
String message = "0101100010000100011000000100010000010000010000000000000001101101";

List<Long> result = Arrays.asList(message.split("(?<=\\G.{6})"))
        .stream().map(bin -> Long.parseLong(bin, 2))
        .collect(toList());
```

Outputs

```
22
8
17
32
17
1
1
0
0
6
13
```

---

**Details**

1. `message.split("(?<=\\G.{6})")` split 6 by 6 numbers
2. `map(bin -> Long.parseLong(bin, 2))` convert each element from binary to Long
3. `collect(toList())` collect the result as a List of Long

Comment: okay thanks for your answer.  it's safe raw of code . but it's must be constant of split by 6 ? how to change by input?